# c comparator best practice for when more arguments needed

Tags: c, comparator, qsort

I intend to sort an array of multidimentional points each time by another coordinate.
I want to use c qsort() method but in order to do so I have to use comparator function which its input is only two pointers, so I can't send it the desired coordinate to sort by.
Therefore I figured out two solutions and I am struggling choosing the best one of them :

1. Use a static variable - an int in this example - initialize it to a -1, and before calling the qsort function set it to the wanted coordinate. In addition, make my comparator, access this variable and compare based on it.
2. Build a new struct to hold a pointer to the point and the desired coordinate, then make the comparator to sort two pointers to such struct and use the additional info from the struct.

The first sounds like a quick solution though it might be loop hole, while the second sounds like an overkill for such a simple task.
I would be glad to hear any better solution if there is to the problem.

Comment: Why not show some code instead of describing it? How you store the points matters a great deal to the solution you can get.

Comment: I'd always plump for (2) and suck it.

Comment: @Bathsheba option 2 could get very expensive for large arrays of points.

Comment: there is possibly a 3rd option - have different comparators for each of the coordinates?

Comment: If so, then either use `qsort_r` as you detail in your fine answer, or nick the source for `qsort_r` if your platform doesn't have it.

Answer (score 2):

If your system has [qsort_r](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort_r), you can use that. qsort_r has an extra parameter that you can use to pass your coordinate in.

```
int comparator(const void *l, const void *r, void *param)
{
    Point* lPoint = (Point*) l;
    Point* rPoint = (Point*) r;
    Coordinate* coord = (Coordinate*) param;

    // Do your comparison ....
}

void mySort(Point* list, size_t listSize, Coordinate sortCoord)
{
    qsort_r(list, listSize, sizeof(Point), comparator, &sortCoord);
}
```

It's definitely available if you are using glibc (e.g. on Linux) and on OS X. However, it is not officially portable. See this answer on portability

[How portable is the re-entrant qsort_r function compared to qsort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300896/how-portable-is-the-re-entrant-qsort-r-function-compared-to-qsort)

My code example is written for the Linux version. With OS X, the comparator must be declared as

```
 int comparator( void *param, const void *l, const void *r)
```

and the qsort_r call is

```
qsort_r(list, listSize, sizeof(Point), &sortCoord, comparator);
```

Comment: Nice. Have an upvote. It's probably juvenile to suggest pinching the source if your platform doesn't have `qsort_r`, but I would be tempted.

Comment: @Bathsheba There's an implementation of qsort_r in glibc and another in OS X's libc. Both of these are open source, therefore using their source code is not only not pinching but encouraged (provided you comply with the licence terms, of course).

Comment: Note that the specification of `qsort_r` differs on Linux and Mac.  The placement of the extra parameter is different, IIRC.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. In fact, my answer as written is wrong for both OS X and Linux! I'll edit it.

Comment: Note http://stackoverflow.com/q/39560773/15168 for info about Mac vs Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The most portable version would probably indeed be to encapsulate the comparsion object(s) ("functors") in a separate file, then use a static file scope variable to change the behavior of the function.

something.h

```
void set_something (something_t s);

int compare_something (const void* obj1, const void* obj2);
```

something.c

```
#include "something.h"

static something_t someting = 0;

void set_something (something_t s)
{
  something = s;
}

int compare_something (const void* obj1, const void* obj2)
{
  const coord_t* c1 = obj1;
  const coord_t* c2 = obj2;

  // do stuff with c1, c2 based on something
}
```

The only down-side with this is that you can't have multiple threads performing different kinds of sorting at the same time, but that's not likely to be an issue. (If it is, design some way to pass a "something" variable as parameter to each thread callback instead.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an option #3

C11 presents `qsort_s()` which provides the needed *context* parameter.  This is in *Annex K (normative)* and so may not be included in C11 compliant compiler.
The availability of this function may not be wide.

> K.3.6.3.2 The qsort_s function

```
errno_t qsort_s(void *base, rsize_t nmemb, rsize_t size,
    int (*compar)(const void *x, const void *y,
    void *context), void *context);
```

> ... The third argument to the comparison function is the
>   `context` argument passed to `qsort_s`. The sole use of `context` by `qsort_s` is to pass it to the comparison function

---

If this function is not available, consider an alternative that mimics this interface.

This idea is similar to the [@JeremyP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42949918/2410359) which suggest [qsort_r](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort_r).  The two functions are similar, except for argument order amongst `qsort_r()` variants the return type.